# Point to document.body of different html

Tags: javascript, html, document, document-body

I am able to retrieve the the body pointed to current html page through `document.body` usage. Can anyone please suggest how to get the pointer to `document.body` of an other html page from the current one.

Example. I am currently in a.html. `document.body` gives a pointer for body of a.html. But I need a pointer to the body tag of b.html from a.html.

Can anyone please suggest the javascript command for the same

Comment: You can only get to the `body` of another page if that page was written into a window that was created (`window.open()`) by the first page. Otherwise, you cannot do this. And, that is a good thing.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements. You only have access to the page you're on; nothing else makes sense. This sounds like an XY problem--what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to modify Page B based on user interaction with Page A?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM)

Comment: @AlexK What does that page have to do with the question?

Comment: @ScottMarcus the page explains how to request the contents of another html page and parse the response into a DOM to be accessed.

Comment: @AlexK That will allow you to parse the results of something that has been retrieved into the first page. The OP is asking how to connect to another page.

Comment: Basically, i have to parse the second page completely and search for a string and return the result in the first page!